How to get contract logs using a hardhat script?
I have this contract in sepolia:
https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0x9f7BBeF51268AC73e2787d48Df50A7Ed4032f8c6#code
Code:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.2;

contract Account {}

contract Root {

    event NewAccount(address add);

    function createAccount() public returns (address newAccount) {
        Account the_account = new Account();
        emit NewAccount(address(the_account));
        return address(the_account);
    }

}

And it returns an event on account (contract) creation.
But my hardhat script is not showing the logs or events after the account creation call,
Hardhat script:
const hre = require("hardhat");

async function main() {

    const chainId = await hre.getChainId();

    const ACCOUNT_MASTER = "0xe4379A25a0DB888E19eC2c14416Fe68a62Aca5cc";

    const ROOT = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("Root");
    const root = await ROOT.attach("0x9f7BBeF51268AC73e2787d48Df50A7Ed4032f8c6");
    res = await root.createAccount({from: ACCOUNT_MASTER});
    console.log(res);

}

main()
    .then(() => process.exit(0)) 
    .catch((error) => { 
        console.error(error);
        process.exit(1);
    }
);

Output:
{
   hash: '0xba785068830d0da41f6c20c78f9b1d8ac54d09c84370277abfedc69d241172ab',
   type: 2,
   accessList: [],
   blockHash: null,
   blockNumber: null,
   transactionIndex: null,
   confirmations: 0,
   from: '0xe4379A25a0DB888E19eC2c14416Fe68a62Aca5cc',
   gasPrice: BigNumber { value: "1627712964" },
   maxPriorityFeePerGas: BigNumber { value: "1500000000" },
   maxFeePerGas: BigNumber { value: "1627712964" },
   gasLimit: BigNumber { value: "67982" },
   to: '0x9f7BBeF51268AC73e2787d48Df50A7Ed4032f8c6',
   value: BigNumber { value: "0" },
   nonce: 173,
   data: '0x9dca362f',
   r: '0xf7eb88ac4b69fec59e509915af90995f2d2b0876b99fd56a6326cb650429b158',
   s: '0x57f81b3defa2da4f2eb70ce128e69940d7fab5b079e49b9ebb3ae9912c095c81',
   v: 0,
   creates: null,
   chainId: 11155111,
   wait: [Function (anonymous)]
 }
The transaction has an Event "NewAccount" which is not present in the output:
https://sepolia.etherscan.io/tx/0xba785068830d0da41f6c20c78f9b1d8ac54d09c84370277abfedc69d241172ab#eventlog
Any help?
I was expecting to get the logs with the newaccount event on it
